# Parsed list items not correctly shown in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I tried to parse JSON data from URL in appcelerator. I parsed all data and tried to out it in a list view. But it shows only last item in the parsed data.(if 10 values available, it show only 10th value). Here is my code and XML data.

```
  var contactList = [];

    var contactsArray,cId,cName,cEmail,cAddr,cGender;
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({  

        onload : function() {

            var jsonParse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            for (var i = 0; i < jsonParse.contacts.length; i++) {
                contactsArray = jsonParse.contacts[i];

                cId = contactsArray.id;
                cName = contactsArray.name;
                cEmail = contactsArray.email;
                cAddr = contactsArray.address;
                cGender = contactsArray.gender;

                var elementData;
                contactList = [];

                contactData = {
                    "name_label" : {
                        text : cName,
                    },
                    "email_label" : {
                        text : cEmail,
                    },
                    "addr_label" : {
                        text : cAddr,
                    },
                    "gender_label" : {
                        text : cGender,
                    },
                    "template" : "list_template_wh",
                    "properties" : {
                        itemId : cId,
                        backgroundColor : "transparent"
                    }
                };
                contactList.push(contactData);
            };
            $.contactListView.sections[0].setItems(contactList);
        },

        onerror : function() {
            Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        },
        timeout : 5000
    });
    xhr.open("GET", Alloy.Globals.AppURL);
    xhr.send();


    This is my xml code


<Alloy>
    <Window id="win_main" title="Window Main">
        <ListView id="contactListView" >
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate name="list_template_wh" id="list_temp_wh">
                    <View  id="list_item_container">
                        <Label bindId="name_label" id="contact_name"/>
                        <Label bindId="email_label" id="contact_email"/>
                        <Label bindId="addr_label" id="contact_addr"/>
                        <Label bindId="gender_label" id="contact_gen"/>
                    </View>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>
            <ListSection/>
        </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your redefine the `contactList` array inside your for loop.
Remove `contactList = [];` juste after `var elementData;` inside your loop.